# Online venues that promote networking among scholars -- alternatives to Academia.edu and ResearchGate

Tags: online-resource, networking, social-media

Are there alternatives to Academia.edu and ResearchGate if one is searching for a venue that promotes "informal" (*) cooperation and networking among scholars (specifically, in mathematics and science)?

(*)  As far as I know, the aim of two sites mentioned above is mostly sharing papers rather than opinions, insights, and interesting material of various sorts related to research. I would like this alternative site to be more informal: a scholarly social network rather a mere preprints repository.

Comment: In mathematics, there is [relatively] a lot of people on G+. (My only reason to use G+ :)).

Comment: Mathoverflow has been used in this way somewhat, for math...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a neat commented [list](http://www.kent.ac.uk/library/research/collaboration/?tab=academic-networking) of academic networking sites at the web site of Library Services -- Information Services at the University of Kent (UK) and an [article](http://www.inthelibrarywiththeleadpipe.org/2008/social-networking-with-a-brain-a-critical-review-of-academic-sites/) reviewing a few academic networking web sites.
Another, shorter and comment-free list is [here](http://srmo.sagepub.com/page/social-networking).
These lists mention, in addition to the sites from the other answers, the following sites (I list them in no particular order)

- http://www.mynetresearch.com
- http://www.methodspace.com/
- https://www.epernicus.com/network
- http://www.geazle.com/
- https://www.mysciencework.com/

Also [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/), just like Mendeley, offers some networking capabilities.

Finally, here is one more fairly new site which is not on the above three lists:

https://chroniclevitae.com/

A number of academic networking sites that existed in the past have already went out of business or became a kind of an archive and do not accept new posts and new members (e.g. the [Nature Network](http://blogs.nature.com/ofschemesandmemes/?p=9625)). I have removed such sites from my list.

Comment: Quite impressive. I'll check them out. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: Not yet. I make do with RG so far.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried linkedIn? They have tons of mathematics groups on there you just have to use the search bar. Or have you tried joining a meetup group? You can go to www.meetup.com and find groups of you interest that are near you area. It is not solely online but it is a great way to meet different people who have the same interests as you.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably try with some groups at [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/disciplines/mathematics/). It is both a social network and a place where you host, post, share papers and links.

Also, regarding mathematics, [this question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51056/are-there-any-good-websites-for-hosting-discussions-of-mathematical-papers?lq=1) seems to be helpful.